# Like Button doesn't work properly - counting

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like, xfbml, facebook-likebox

I integrated the new Like Button to my Site and discovered that it doesn't work.
Every time you click on "like" it shows shortly the '1' and then it disappeard again.
No likes where counted.
The site is completely new so there never was a like button for this domain.
I tried it from another fb account but the same problem. 
At the same server on another homepage is the old iframe button, works without any problems.

I tried everything but it never works, XFBML, HTML5 and even the old iframe version weren't working.
Here is the code from the iframe which is currently integrated.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fbemit.eu&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This is the answer the fb server sended back when trying to like:

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"jsmods":{"require":[["Plugin","disconnect",[],["http://bemit.eu/"]]]}}

Sorry for my english, but i'm hopefully that somebody could help me.
If possible i want the new like button not the old.

Comment: same happens to me when i put the like button on my tumblr. did anybody find a solution to this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's solved. I will tell you the reason.
Facebook has a url's cache.
That cache can be cleaned when you debug the url here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Go there and see what's going wrong with your url and facebook meta-tags, that cache should be cleaned and everything will be fine.
If in the future you have problems with like buttons or information shared (og meta tags), you could use that link.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and finally found what is it.

If you set your like button to the domain. And the initial page of the domain does redirects to different pages (for example: languages, mobile version) the counter doesn't work. It got cached from different pages and fails.

Set the like button to the real page.